# Line Appending in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hi I have the input data in below format, I need the data as in Output section.

```
2004/08/15,12345,12345,xyz,9876,45678,  
45348753475,This is Test, This has to append in upper line(0)  
02/05/7,12345,12345,xyz,9876,45678,  
32984573475,This is Test, This has to append in upper line(1)  
99/3/10,12345,12345,xyz,9876,45678,  
This has to append in upper line(2)
```

Output :

```
1999/08/25,12345,12345,xyz,9876,45678,45348753475,This line has to append in upper line(0)
04/04/7,12345,12345,xyz,9876,45678,This is Test,32984573475,This has to append in upper line(1)
99/3/10,12345,12345,xyz,9876,45678,This has to append in upper line(2)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Can't you just replace ,\n to ,

Comment: No Jerry, Still on the Job

Comment: oh, hard question for the date calculation. `02/05/7 -> 04/04/7`

Comment: Sorry Kent, That was typo mistake..it should be same.

Comment: You tagged the question with [tag:regex], so I'm assuming you know at least some of the basics. Do you know what do you have to match in your input data?

Comment: It should look for date

Comment: How do you match a date in regex?

Comment: I would prefer to search for date format (not exact date)

Comment: Okay, and how would you go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
search: \s*?\n(?![0-9]{2,4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2})
replace: nothing
```

details:

```
\s*?     # zero or more white characters until ...
\n       # ... a newline
(?![0-9]{2,4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}) # not followed by a date
```

Comment: I think that those lines were dummy lines to make the example easier to understand :)

Comment: Yes Jerry, You are right.

Comment: @Jerry: indeed <°)))))))))))))))>

Comment: Hi,It didn't work, Will you please check again ?Basically it need to look for date.

Comment: @user3223672: I have tested and it works. have you checked the regex checkbox?

Comment: @user3223672: Is your notepad++ version up to date?

Comment: Hi Caisimir, You are great..Though the above syntax is so much closer to what I want, I just modified it a bit like \s*?\n(?![0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}), which gave me exact solution..lot of Kudos..

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

Find what: `,\s*\R`
Replace with: `,`

`\R` stands for any line break ie: `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

Just search and replace in extended mode

```
Search: ,\n
Replace: ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a little smaller and clearer:
Search: ",\n" Replace: ","
or
Search: ",\r\n" Replace: ","

or Regex:
Search: ",\r?\n" Replace ","